# Create Apple developer account

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

In order to create an Apple developer account:

1. Is it necessary to enter name on the credit card as my personal information?
2. When I wanted to purchase, the following error occurred:

   > Your country either does not have an Apple Online Store or does not offer Apple Developer Products for online purchase.

It says I should fill out the purchase form and fax it to a specific number but I'm currently travelling. Is it a problem if I send the form from another country (and not the one where I reside)?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a support issue for iTunes Connect.  I recommend asking in Apple's developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/ if you don't get a response from Apple's specific iTunes Connect support: http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Yes. It will check that the name is the same as on the credit card.

2: What country do you live in?

Comment: Azerbaijan But now i'm in another country

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer for some relavent information:
[apple-developer-program-enrollment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408838/apple-developer-program-enrollment/6408939#6408939).

I don't know about availability in your country, but in US, if I was away from home, I could have someone at home get a "Prepaid Credit Gift-Card", then link it to my name and home-address and make the payment for me from home.