# Apple Developer Program Enrollment

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

Can i enroll for Apple Developer Program from different country because Apple Online Store is unavailable in my country, and can someone else pay for my account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can technically enroll from any country, regardless of country.

I know of a man that had the same problem in Ukraine. His problem was solved by depositing the money via a bank account to a bank account at Apple. I would contact Apple and wait about 48 hours before taking any actions because usually that's the time apple needs to reply to mails.

Please don't ever trust random people to pay for services like this. If they paid for your developer account, the developer account technically belongs to them, and so do their contained products ;]

Comment: To complete my purchase at apple developer program, they want to complete and fax the Purchase Form. How can i skip this step and deposit money to a bank account at Apple? And can i deposit money via paypal to apple or only with bank account?

Comment: As i mentioned, write a mail directly to them. The solution might be different between regions, and i have honestly not tried going through this myself, only talked to people who have tried it.